# How to get rid of this numerical issue in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, precision, floating-accuracy

I have an array to represent time that goes:

```
t = linspace(-30,30,N);
```

Then I perform the following operation:

```
plot(sech(t) + 1e-4 - sech(t))
```

which gives the following plot:

[image: plot]

Normally, it wouldn't be a huge issue, but sometimes I deal with signals with magnitudes of the order of `1e-4` and this starts to interfere there.

Comment: sech(t) is in the range of [0,1]. The values of sech(t) is at most 1e+4 times 1e-4. And unfortunately, this is based on a realistic problem I am trying to model.

Comment: You are not really plotting `sech(t) + 1e-4 - sech(t)`, are you? If you wanted to plot that, you could plot `1e-4` instead. Show the actual expression you are plotting.

Comment: Oh this is not what I am plotting. I am dealing with an issue where I receive a DC-perturbed signal (the sech(t) + 1e-4) and I know the actual signal beforehand (sech(t)). So here I need to subtract the two to obtain the perturbation. I was running into some issues because when I did the above operation, I would get a widely incorrect solution to my problem but when I manually supplied 1e-4, I would get the right solution. This is when I thought I'd plot this and I saw this.....

Comment: .. Ideally, for some other operation I will be doing, I need the input to be 1e-4. I am not supposed to know the DC difference between the two signals beforehand. The precision error seems to be messing with stuff.

Comment: You know the error here is miniscule and the apparent magnitude is a distortion of the scale of the graph? It is not reasonable to be plotting a graph with a vertical scale that various somewhere around 10^-12 relative to the value. Set the y axis to run from 0 to 2e-4, so the 1e-4 signal would be in the middle, and there will not be any visible variation.